# Is it better to use graphics or BitmapData for filling with a colour and using blendMode = HARDLIGHT?

Tags: actionscript, haxe

I'm working on a very basic **day/dusk/night** overlay for a simple 2d game.

I will use a **blendMode = HARDLIGHT**, interpolating from a table with different colours and opacity based on the current game time. Then every N frames will redraw the overlay.

It's a trivial matter but since I don't have a clear opinion, what do you think, is it better for this to:

- draw using Sprite.graphics,
- or to use a BitmapData.

(I was thinking also thinking of using a ColorMatrix but I don't think I can replicate the HARDLIGHT blendMode in that case).

Using *graphics* it seems easier to avoid memory leaks, do you agree?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapData is much faster than vector graphics because vector rendering required math to fill your shape.

Comment: But math is performed only during the preparation isn't it? Say my sprite filled using graphics then just stays in front of the rendered scene (without translation nor rotation), wouldn't it run at the same speed?

Comment: Use any transition or not, your vector will calculate and draw on every enter frame.